# Apexchart Legend toggle series issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, apexcharts

In my chart, I have two series of data: weather data with over 2000 entries and air quality data with some null values. The chart displays both series in the legend. When I click on a legend name associated with data, it hides or shows that specific series accordingly. However, when I click on a legend name associated with null data, it hides both legend names and the entire chart. How can I handle this situation?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-swirles-vp2z5c?file=/src/App.js) click here for reference

Comment: In your codesandbox the file `jsonData1.js` doesn't contain any data. I added just one data point and it seems to work.

Comment: The issue I am facing is that when the chart has no data and I click on a legend name, the entire graph toggles, and I have to refresh the page to see the data. How can I reset the graph without refreshing the entire page?